# Show a component in another component when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to view information from a dummy module when I click a component. I have tried a few methods but i'm pretty new to react so i haven't had any success.

I have one component that projects some of the information of each element in the module as a list, and I want to be able to click it, and show extended information of that specific element in another component.

So far this is what i have:

**ListOfData.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/ListOfData.css'
import ListOfDataElement from "./ListOfDataElement";
import DummyListContent from "./DummyListContent";
function ListOfData() {
    const dataComponent = DummyListContent.map(item => <ListOfDataElement key={item.id} product={item}/>)

    return (
        <div className="ListOfData_container">
            {dataComponent}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListOfData
```

**ListOfDataElements.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import '../css/ListOfData.css'
function ListOfDataElement(props: any) {
    return(
        <div className={'ListOfDataElement'} onClick={() => alert('test')}>
            <h3>{props.product.id} - {props.product.name}<i className={'arrow right'}/></h3>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ListOfDataElement
```

**InfoOfData.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/InfoOfData.css'

function InfoOfData() {

    return (
        <div className="InfoOfData_container" id="InfoContainer">

        </div>
        )

}

export default InfoOfData
```

**InfoOfDataElement.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

function InfoOfDataElement(props:any) {

    return(
        <div className={'ListOfDataElement'}>
            <h3>{props.product.name}</h3>
            <h4>Spent: {props.product.spent}</h4>
            <p>Description: {props.product.description}</p>
        </div>
    )

}
export default InfoOfDataElement
```

**DummyListContent.tsx**

```
const content = [
    {
        id: "#1",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 1,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    },
    {
        id: "#2",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 4,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    },
    {
        id: "#3",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 1,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    },
    {
        id: "#4",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 2,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    },
    {
        id: "#5",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 1,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    },
    {
        id: "#6",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 3,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    },
    {
        id: "#7",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 5,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    },
    {
        id: "#8",
        name: "Placeholder",
        spent: 4,
        description: "Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder."
    }
]

export default content
```

My goal is to make InfoOfDataElement show the rest of the information for the clicked ListOfDataElement element, and render it inside InfoOfData.

Comment: First your `InfoOfData` is pretty much doing nothing except returning a div element. If you want to display `InfoOfDataElement` inside it you need to import it and return it as well (inside the div or as root element). Second, and this one is a question, are `ListOfData` and `InfoOfData/InfoOfDataElement` in the same parent component?

Comment: Yeah i know. There is nothing there now because i'm not sure how to pass what i want to display. But you can imagine it's there. Second, ListOfData and InfoOfData is inside the same parent component, together with another one.  InfoOfDataElement should be the child of InfoOfData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code sandbox working as I assume you want it to work.
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bouman-rh50w?file=/src/App.js)

Well basically you would need a state to hold the selected element.

Assume you click on the button, then you would trigger a callback to change the state of the parent component (App) and since we pass the `selected` state as props to the children (ListOfData, InfoOfData, etc...) React would automatically pickup the state change and re render the content in InfoOfData and it's child InfoOfDataElement.

I just left out the button part but as long as you had a button and change the `onClick` event to that button it will work.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what i want to do! Nice! Only thing is i need to rewrite some of the declaration to fit Typescript. I have a file `DataContent.tsx` where I want to add the components. The `setSelected(DummyListContent.find((el) => el.id: === id))` needs to be changed to be spesific.

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "be specific"?

Comment: No worries! I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to react myself and I didn't understand 100% what you wanted to do, but ill do my best to help you achieve what you are trying to do,
if you want to render a component in react you have few ways, changing local state
is one of the easiest ways, in the next example (I don't know if it works! I may miss something) I used state for the data and that will render the component as well
so if you pass a state the button will get the new state as well and trigger a render.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/InfoOfData.css'

function InfoOfData() {
const [state,myState] = useState(//the data to transfer)

    return (
        <div className="InfoOfData_container" id="InfoContainer">
           <button onClick={()=><InfoOfDataElement props={state}/>}
        </div>
        )

}

export default InfoOfData
```

Comment: My button will be the ListOfDataElement component. I want to be able to press that and InfoOfData will load InfoOfDataElement with the information from the id of the ListOfDataElement component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/ListOfData.css'
import ListOfDataElement from "./ListOfDataElement";
import DummyListContent from "./DummyListContent";

function ListOfData() {
    return (
      <div>

     {
       DummyListContent.map((item,key) => {
         return (
           <div className='container' key={item.id}>
             <ListOfDataElement id={item.id} product={item}/>
           </div>
         )
       }
    )
}

export default ListOfData;
```

```
import React from "react";
import '../css/ListOfData.css'
function ListOfDataElement({ product }) {
    return(
        <div className={'ListOfDataElement'} onClick={() => alert('test')}>
            <h3>{id} - {name}<i className={'arrow right'}/></h3>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ListOfDataElement
```

Comment: This will only list all of the ListOfDataElement like i have done already. I want only one element to appear. The one corresponding to the ID of the one i click.

Comment: So when you click an element you want to be routed to another page with that elements information?

Comment: No, I want let's say all of the information corresponding to the id of the element clicked (i.e. id, name, spent, description) to show inside InfoOfData via InfoOfDataElement. I have written the structure of the component inside InfoOfDataElement, but the logic for displaying that I don't know. All of the content will be displayed on one single page.

Answer (score 0):

InfoOfData component has state with selected product and pass function `onSelectItem`
to children item on the list

```
import React from 'react'
import DummyListContent from "./DummyListContent";
import InfoOfDataElement from "./InfoOfDataElement";
import ListOfData from "./ListOfData";
import '../css/InfoOfData.css'

function InfoOfData() {

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

    const onSelectItem = (item) => {
        setSelected(item);
    }

    return (
        <div className="InfoOfData_container" id="InfoContainer">
            {selected && <InfoOfDataElement product={selected} />} // Render if product is on state
            <ListOfData onSelect={onSelectItem} /> // There we pass function as prop
            
        </div>
        )

}

export default InfoOfData
```

List pass onSelect as prop to children

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/ListOfData.css'
import ListOfDataElement from "./ListOfDataElement";

function ListOfData(props) {
    const { list = [], onSelect } = props; // pass list
    const dataComponent = list.map(item => <ListOfDataElement key={item.id} product={item} onSelect={onSelect} />)

    return (
        <div className="ListOfData_container">
            {dataComponent}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListOfData
```

List item call function onSelect with product to Parent

```
import React from "react";
import '../css/ListOfData.css'
function ListOfDataElement(props: any) {
    const { onSelect, product } = props;

    const onSelectProduct = () => onSelect(product); // Call prop function onSelect

    return(
        <div className={'ListOfDataElement'} onClick={onSelectProduct}>
            <h3>{props.product.id} - {props.product.name}<i className={'arrow right'}/></h3>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ListOfDataElement
```

Please check all imports and props